# Boxplot comparison in R - how do I display p-values in vertical lines within a boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, p-value

I generated a boxplot and tested the differences in means of the to vectors x1 and x2 with `wilcox.test`. How can I implement the test result in the boxplot?

```
> x1 <- rnorm(1000)
> x2 <- rnorm(1000) +10
> wilcox.test(x1,x2, paired=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
V = 0, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> boxplot(x1, x2)
```

Thank you guys!

R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
text(x=1, y=10, labels="p-value<0.0001")
```

I am a newbie with R, but if you input your **x** and **y** coordinates and input your labels you could input your test results manually on your graph.

I am sure you already know this, but *\n* would be used to make a brake in your labels.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as described [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000) +10
dt =  tibble(x1, x2) %>% pivot_longer(1:2)

my_comparisons <- list( c("x1", "x2") )
ggboxplot(dt, x = "name", y = "value",
          color = "name", palette = "jco")+ 
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, method.args = list(paired=TRUE))
```